# GetKeyDown sends multiple outputs

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

specifically it sends as many outputs as there are objects with the code in them that allows them to be interacted with, even if I press E when not looking at anything. I wanted to make an inventory system, but this causes all objects that have this code to be interacted with. I included all the scripts that im using for this system if that can help. I genuinely don't know what I did wrong

the interactor code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Events;
using System;

public class Interactable : MonoBehaviour
{
public LayerMask interactableLayerMask;

//ITEM VARIABLE
public Item item;

//PICK UP RADIUS
public float radius = 4f;

public void Interact()
{
    Debug.Log("Interacted with " + transform.name);
    PickUp();
}

//PICK UP INTERACTION
void PickUp()
{
    Debug.Log("Picking up " + item.name);
    bool wasPickedUp = Inventory.instance.Add(item);

    if (wasPickedUp)
        Destroy(gameObject);
}


//INTERACTION
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
    {
        Debug.Log("Added item -----------------------------------------");
        RaycastHit hit;

        if (Physics.Raycast(Camera.main.transform.position, Camera.main.transform.forward, out hit, radius))
        {
            Interactable interactable = hit.collider.GetComponent<Interactable>();
            if (interactable != null)
            {
                Interact();
            }
        } else
        {
            Debug.Log("Nothing");
        }
    }
}
}
```

the Inventory code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Inventory : MonoBehaviour
{
#region Singleton

public static Inventory instance;

void Awake()
{
    if (instance != null)
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("More than one instance of Inventory found!");
        return;
    }
    instance = this;
}
#endregion

public delegate void OnItemChanged();
public OnItemChanged onItemChangedCallback;
    

public int space = 20;

public List<Item> items = new List<Item>();

public bool Add (Item item)
{
    if (!item.isDefaultItem)
    {
        if (items.Count >= space)
        {
            Debug.Log("Note enough space in inventory");
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            items.Add(item);

            if (onItemChangedCallback != null)
                onItemChangedCallback.Invoke();
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public void Remove(Item item)
{
    items.Remove(item);

    if (onItemChangedCallback != null)
        onItemChangedCallback.Invoke();
}

}
```

Item code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "New Item", menuName = "Inventory/Item")]

public class Item : ScriptableObject
{
    new public string name = "New Item";
    public Sprite icon = null;
    public bool isDefaultItem = false;
}
```

Comment: Whether the inventory can adopt the design mode of mvc, please write the method related to the data in the MODEL. Then what will be the method to analyze the inventory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my understanding, your code goes into the `Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E)` for every object in the scene, but it does not add it to the inventory.

That is because you use the `Update` function in the Interactable class, which are your objects. Instead, try moving the exact same block of code into your Inventory class. Make sure you make your Interact method public, so you can call it.

Comment: Thank you so much! It really helped. However I encountered another problem: the "items" are assigned to gameObjects, and instead of interacting with the object I click on it interacts with the last created object. Except the debug tells me the raycast hit the correct object, but when it calls the Interact() function it says that it "Interacted with " the last created gameObject. Right up until Interact() console returns to me the correct object, but once it reaches Interact() func it just tells me the last created object

Comment: So your block of code should be something like:

            if (interactable != null)
            {
                interactable.Interact();
            }

If you debug in that if statement, does it show the correct item?

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't quite understand how to do that. I made a post with all the codes involved this this, would you be able to take a look? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71872676/when-interacting-with-an-object-and-adding-it-to-inventory-it-adds-the-last-crea

Comment: Nevermind the last comment, the solution helped. Thank you so much for you help!