# When interacting with an object and adding it to inventory it adds the last created gameObject

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

So the game knows what object it hit right up until the Interact() function is called in the Interactable script. I've used Debugs to try and find where the issue is and it seems to be that function, or rather in that script.

I want to make the game read which gameObject it hit and then put the "Item" it has assigned to that object to then add to the Inventory and delete the object, and it does that, except it adds the last created gameObject specifically. If I swap the "Items" in the gameObjects it will still start adding and deleting objects from the last created one.

I've attached all the scripts that are involved in this if that can help, but from what I can tell it's a problem with the Interactable script.

My best guess would be to somehow make the Interactable script think it's not the last created object, but I couldn't find info on how I could do that.

I'm sorry for this question with a huge amount of code, I hope it's not too much for a question

mouseLook:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class mouseLook : MonoBehaviour
{

public bool hasInteracted = false;
public bool wasFpressed = false;


public float mouseSensitivity = 100f;

public Transform playerBody;

float xRotation = 0f;

public float radius = 4f;


void Start()
{
    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
}

void Update()
{
    float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
    float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;

    xRotation -= mouseY;
    xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -90f, 90f);

    transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, 0f, 0f);
    playerBody.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseX);


    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
    {
        wasFpressed = true;
        RaycastHit hit;

        if (Physics.Raycast(Camera.main.transform.position, Camera.main.transform.forward, out hit, radius))
        {
            Interactable interactable = hit.collider.GetComponent<Interactable>();
            Debug.Log(interactable);
            

            if (interactable != null)
            {
                hasInteracted = true;
            }
            
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Nothing");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Interactable:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Events;
using System;

public class Interactable : MonoBehaviour
{
public LayerMask interactableLayerMask;

public Item item;

public mouseLook inter;

public virtual void Interact()
{
    //at this point the console tells me the gameObject is the last created object
    Debug.Log(gameObject);
}


void Update()
{
    if (inter.hasInteracted && inter.wasFpressed)
    {
        inter.hasInteracted = false;
        inter.wasFpressed = false;
        Interact();
    }
}
}
```

ItemPickup:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ItemPickup : Interactable
{

public override void Interact()
{
    base.Interact();
    Debug.Log("Interacted with " + item.name);
    PickUp();
}


void PickUp()
{
    Debug.Log("Picking up " + item.name);
    bool wasPickedUp = Inventory.instance.Add(item);

    if (wasPickedUp)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
        Debug.Log("Destroyed Item");
    }
}
}
```

Inventory:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Inventory : MonoBehaviour
{
#region Singleton

public static Inventory instance;

void Awake()
{
    if (instance != null)
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("More than one instance of Inventory found!");
        return;
    }
    instance = this;
}
#endregion

public delegate void OnItemChanged();
public OnItemChanged onItemChangedCallback;
    

public int space = 20;

public List<Item> items = new List<Item>();

public bool Add (Item item)
{
    if (!item.isDefaultItem)
    {
        if (items.Count >= space)
        {
            Debug.Log("Note enough space in inventory");
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            items.Add(item);

            if (onItemChangedCallback != null)
                onItemChangedCallback.Invoke();
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public void Remove(Item item)
{
    items.Remove(item);

    if (onItemChangedCallback != null)
        onItemChangedCallback.Invoke();
}

}
```

Item:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "New Item", menuName = "Inventory/Item")]

public class Item : ScriptableObject
{
new public string name = "New Item";
public Sprite icon = null;
public bool isDefaultItem = false;
}
```

Comment: Inside of your raycast you get the interactable object.  After checking it is not null, call `interactable.Interact();`.  Not sure why you need those booleans for interacting and pressed F, since those conditions are met when you find the interactable in the raycast section.

Comment: Thanks! your solution helped, as according to the debug the clicked object is interacted first, but now it just picks up all items with the ItemPickup script at the same time. As for the bools, it was my poor attempt at fixing the exact issue that I wrote in this comment, but it seems like it didn't help

Comment: NEVERMIND, I just had to remove code from void Update in the Interactable. Thanks again!

Comment: When calling the interactable.Interact() method, do you have to judge that the object is not empty?